# Как спарсить(импортировать) файл csv в java объекты

Tags: java

У меня есть файл csv мне нужно спарсить его данные в объекты,

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\test_case.csv"), ';');

    List<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String[]> records = reader.readAll();

    Iterator<String[]> iterator = records.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String[] record = iterator.next();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setSsoid(record[0]);
        emp.setTs(Long.parseLong(record[1]));
        emp.setGrp(record[2]);
        emp.setType(record[3]);
        emp.setSubtype(record[4]);
        emp.setUrl(record[5]);
        emp.setOrgid(record[6]);
        emp.setFormid(record[7]);
        emp.setCode(record[8]);
        emp.setLtpa(record[9]);
        emp.setSudirresponse(record[10]);
        emp.setYmdh(record[11]);

        emps.add(emp);
    }
```

при попытке исполнить следующий код, вылазит такое исключение ->

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ts"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:692)
at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
at tt.main(tt.java:38)
```

код модели:

```
public class Employee {
private String ssoid;
private long ts;
private String grp;
private String type;
private String subtype;
private String url;
private String orgid;
private String formid;
private String code;
private String ltpa;
private String sudirresponse;
private String ymdh;

public Employee() {
}

public Employee(String ssoid, long ts, String grp, String subtype, String url, String orgid, String formid, String code, String ltpa, String sudirresponse, String ymdh) {
    this.ssoid = ssoid;
    this.ts = ts;
    this.grp = grp;
    this.subtype = subtype;
    this.url = url;
    this.orgid = orgid;
    this.formid = formid;
    this.code = code;
    this.ltpa = ltpa;
    this.sudirresponse = sudirresponse;
    this.ymdh = ymdh;
}

public String getSsoid() {
    return ssoid;
}

public void setSsoid(String ssoid) {
    this.ssoid = ssoid;
}

public long getTs() {
    return ts;
}

public void setTs(long ts) {
    this.ts = ts;
}

public String getGrp() {
    return grp;
}

public void setGrp(String grp) {
    this.grp = grp;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getSubtype() {
    return subtype;
}

public void setSubtype(String subtype) {
    this.subtype = subtype;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getOrgid() {
    return orgid;
}

public void setOrgid(String orgid) {
    this.orgid = orgid;
}

public String getFormid() {
    return formid;
}

public void setFormid(String formid) {
    this.formid = formid;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getLtpa() {
    return ltpa;
}

public void setLtpa(String ltpa) {
    this.ltpa = ltpa;
}

public String getSudirresponse() {
    return sudirresponse;
}

public void setSudirresponse(String sudirresponse) {
    this.sudirresponse = sudirresponse;
}

public String getYmdh() {
    return ymdh;
}

public void setYmdh(String ymdh) {
    this.ymdh = ymdh;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "ssoid='" + ssoid + '\'' +
            ", ts=" + ts +
            ", grp='" + grp + '\'' +
            ", subtype='" + subtype + '\'' +
            ", url='" + url + '\'' +
            ", orgid='" + orgid + '\'' +
            ", formid='" + formid + '\'' +
            ", code='" + code + '\'' +
            ", ltpa='" + ltpa + '\'' +
            ", sudirresponse='" + sudirresponse + '\'' +
            ", ymdh='" + ymdh + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть причина? и как всё таки правильно это дело сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В record[1] лежит строка "ts", при вызове Long.parseLong с таким значением выкидывается NumberFormatException. В зависимости от требований, вам нужно либо вставить проверку входящих значений, обработку ошибки, либо поправить данные в csv

Comment: У меня в  csv файле первая строка это название так сказать столбцов, можно узнать как сделать прочитывание файла сразу со второй строки, т.е со значений? Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: вызовите `iterator.next();` перез циклом

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы, появился еще один вопрос, есть ли способы парсинга в объекты красивей, а не так хардкодно как у меня?

Comment: Вам подойдет библиоткеа десериализации из CSV в java-объекты. Например, Jackson (jackson-dataformat-csv), который позволяет через аннотации в классе указать как парсить и раскладывать в поля данные из CSV